# Array index(es) remain null after accessed and defined from other classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, null

I am having bad time solving this problem, well the thing is, I am trying to store several strings inside array, here's the declaration of it:

```
public static String [][][] Day = new String [ 9 ][ 5 ][ 3 ];
```

It is declared inside "AgendicusPanel" class (file).

I am also storing data inside this array in other class "AgendicusSQL".

```
public void SQL_Define( String name ) {
    try {

        AgendicusAgenda agenda = new AgendicusAgenda();
        String query = String.format( "SELECT * FROM Korisnici WHERE Username = '%s' LIMIT 1", name );
        rs = st.executeQuery( query );
        while( rs.next() ) {

            AgendicusPanel.mail = rs.getString( "Mail" );
            AgendicusPanel.Dream1 = rs.getString( "Dream1" );
            AgendicusPanel.Dream2 = rs.getString( "Dream2" );
            AgendicusPanel.Dream3 = rs.getString( "Dream3" );
            AgendicusPanel.ForToday1 = rs.getString( "ForToday1" );
            AgendicusPanel.ForToday2 = rs.getString( "ForToday2" );
            AgendicusPanel.ForToday3 = rs.getString( "ForToday3" );

            String tempo = null;
            int temprows;
            for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++ ) {
                for( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) {
                    for( int k = 0; k < 3; k++ ) {
                        tempo = String.format( "Day%d%d%d", i, j, k );
                        AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] = rs.getString( tempo );
                        System.out.println( ( AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] == null ) ? ("null") : ( AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] ) + " - "+ tempo );

                    }
                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println( AgendicusPanel.Day[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 0 ] );
        System.out.println( AgendicusPanel.Day[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 1 ] );
        System.out.println( AgendicusPanel.Day[ 0 ][ 0 ][ 2 ] );
        agenda.preloadData();


    } catch( SQLException ex ) {
        System.out.println( ex );
    }
}
```

I've left these prints just to see if the array index values remain the same or do they get changed in proper way.

After query, values are properly stored inside array indexes, e.g.:

```
tempo = String.format( "Day%d%d%d", i, j, k );
AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] = rs.getString( tempo );
System.out.println( ( AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] == null ) ? 
        ("null") : ( AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] ) + " - "+ tempo );
```

Prints inside console log:
    Go to new meeting. - Day000
    2018-9-17 - Day001
    15:00 - Day002

After performing code above, the same array's indexes remain null.

```
null
null
null
```

^^^ same array indexes in other class.
If someone could tell me what am I doing wrong here, or what is the problem, i would be very grateful. Thanks in advance, best regards.

Comment: Are you getting SQL results from your query for columns "Day000", "Day001", and "Day002"?  Are the values null or not null?

Comment: For my money, if this were my problem, I'd use the debugger that comes with my IDE to first isolate *where* the error is, and then take steps to try to debug it.

Comment: This like seems like a culprit AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] = rs.getString( tempo ); Do you have 135 columns in the DB like Day000...Day842.

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab I do have 135 columns for "days", the indexes are correctly defined, here are the values of it after query is done:
Day000 2018-9-17 - Day001 15:00 - Day002

This output was derived by
`tempo = String.format( "Day%d%d%d", i, j, k );
AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] = rs.getString( tempo );
System.out.println( ( AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] == null ) ? 
        ("null") : ( AgendicusPanel.Day[ i ][ j ][ k ] ) + " - "+ tempo );`

The array indexes seem like they are defined 'locally' at a moment, but cannot be accessed in their class where the array is declared.

Comment: Does all rows contain the data. I think 1st row contains the data and subsequent rows don't so it sets to null. You can exit out of the while loop by putting a break and check it.

Comment: I solved it, I've forgot I've added definition for every array in a constructor that's called on initialization of panel. Thanks for help :)

Comment: That's why , it is better to add all the relevant code.